# Overwrite initial value from redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am initializing values in Field using initialValues. Although I would like to overwrite one of the Field with another defaul value.
Is this possible? I was trying with defaultValue etc but I doesnt work. 
This is the part of code I want to change:

```
<Field
  type="text"
  name={`${some}.url`}
  component={renderField}
  label="URL"
  defaultValue={some.url + ':' + some.port}
/>
```

Its initialized with url, but I would like to change it to url:port

Comment: Can you modify the values before you pass it down to the form?

Comment: Use callbacks and you can update them, so that your props are updated

Comment: Values are from API call, so Im not sure that I can update them... 
@FortyTwo any example,please?

Comment: I don't see a reason for using a callback. Just modify the `initialValues` before passing them down to the form, as @HarshaVenkatram already suggested. I've provided a [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804044/4312466).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before passing `initialValues` prop down to your `redux-form` component, you can modify it.

**Something like that:**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  // Here's how to set a default value and overwrite the API initial data.
  // Let's say your form is editing an User.
  // And if the User, returned by the API, doesn't have a name,
  // then we set a default value.
  initialValues: {...state.user, name: state.user.name || 'Default name'}
)}

// `connect` is part of `react-redux`.
// If you don't use `react-redux`, then just modify the `initialValues`
// before passing it down to the form.
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
  form: 'formName',
})(Component))
```

Comment: Thanks to @Harsha Venkatram too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what and how you generate or update your `url` and `port` variables. But something like this should work. If you can share more details, I can adapt the answer.

```
private url: string = `${some}.url`;
private port: string = `${some}.port`;

<Field
  type="text"
  name={this.url}
  component={renderField}
  label="URL"
  defaultValue={this.url + ':' + this.port}
  updateDefaultValue={(url, port) => {this.url = url; this.port = port}}
/>
```

in your `Field` component

```
this.props.updateDefaultValue("xxx","yyy");
```

Hope this helps